# Bash string concatenation, do not expand wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, script, string-manipulation

### Background:

I have a script which takes a filename as a parameter, for example "mydb.sql". My script imports this DB and "cleans" it (removes user identifiable data, etc), exports it and then creates a "lite" version (strips all non-essential data out, leaving only main admin user, removing all votes, etc). These get generated into mydb.clean.sql and mydb.lite.sql. This script gets run on several folders.

I want to create a wildcard pattern to pass into `find`. Originally I just hard coded `'*.sql'` which returned the original, clean and lite (these were then passed into `du` to give me a file size summary).

Now I have altered my script to take a parameter; the filename. This allows me to run it on a single file.

### The Question

So how do I get the pattern? I have this:

```
FNAME=$(basename "$1");
FNAME="${FNAME%.*}*.sql"
echo $FNAME
```

This converts `FNAME` from `/home/user/backups/sitea/mydb.sql` to `mydb`. I then want `FNAME` to be the string `'mydb*.sql'`, however bash is expanding that * out so I end up with `FNAME` as `'mydb.sql mydb.clean.sql mydb.lite.sql'` (assuming it found them in the CWD).

I have tries backslashing the `*`, however I then end up with `'mydb\*.sql'` which doesn't work. I tried using single quotes, but then bash doesn't expand the `${FNAME%.*}` part.

Any thoughts?

### Update

This better illustrates the issue...

```
[user@server temp]$ T="${FNAME}\*.sql"; echo $T
mydb\*.sql

[user@server temp]$ T="${FNAME}*.sql"; echo $T
mydb.clean.sql mydb.lite.sql mydb.sql

[user@server temp]$ T='${FNAME}*.sql'; echo $T
${FNAME}*.sql
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's being expanded at the last step.

```
echo "$FNAME"
```

Comment: Looks like you're right... `T="${FNAME}*.sql"; echo "$T` outputs: `mydb*.sql`

Comment: Of course - it makes sense now. Unquoted variables get expanded. I simply had to add double quotes to the `echo` and the `find` calls and it worked perfectly. Thanks @Ignacio